# Is this Markov Chain calculation correct?

Tags: probability, markov-chains

> $S=\{1,2\}$
>   $\alpha = (1/2, 1/2)$
>   $P= \begin{bmatrix}
> 1/2&1/2\\
> 0&1\end{bmatrix} $
>
> Find
>
> - $P(X_1=1 | X_0=1)$

**Given solution:**

$P(X_1=1 | X_0=1) = \frac{P(X_1=1 , X_0=1)}{P(X_0=1)} = \frac{P(X_1=1)  \cdot  P( X_0=1)}{P(X_0=1)} = 0.5 * 0.5 / 0.5 = 0.5$

---

To me, this is incorrect.

Because, $P(X_1=1) = 0.25$ ....  as $\alpha \cdot P = (0.25, 0.75)$

$P(X_0=1) = 0.5$ is correct as the 1st element of $\alpha = (1/2, 1/2)$  is $0.5$.

So, the answer should be $0.25$.

Comment: Doesn’t seem to me that there’s any calculation required: $P(X_{i+1}=1\mid X_i=1)$ is exactly the $(1,1)$ entry of $P$.

Answer (score 1):

For the calculation you're asked, $P(X_1=1 | X_0=1)$, whatever $\alpha$ is is irrelevant because you're conditioning on the event that $X_0 = 1$. From that perspective, you're not calculating some entry of $\alpha \cdot P$, you're calculating an entry of $(1,0) \cdot P$ (assuming that that is how your state space is constructed).